# Spring Boot pod with multithreading restarts in Kubernetes

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, kubernetes

We have deployed a SpringBoot application in Kubernetes. The application uses ApplicationRunner to get command line arguments from the Kubernetes YAML file and then copies files from a file system to Amazon S3. The copying process always succeeds without error. Ideally, the application should end in the **Completed** state. But it keeps restarting.

```
public class MySpringbootApplication implements ApplicationRunner
```

We have put a check to make sure if it restarts, then it would check if the S3 folder is empty. If not empty, then it should be complete.

With 100 files (it restarts but completes)

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                     READY   STATUS      RESTARTS      AGE
default        springboot-kubernetes-67bb5dcc5-h2fhs     0/1     Completed   1 (18s ago)   56s
```

1 million files (does not work)

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                     READY   STATUS           RESTARTS      AGE
default        springboot-kubernetes-6df4749db4-ng9rd    0/1  CrashLoopBackOff   6 (28s ago)   69m
```

The Application uses multithreading with CompletableFuture. I have tried pool sizes like 10, 60, 250.

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Math.max(pool, 10));

for (String filePath : filePaths)
        futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> processFile(filePath), executors));

CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()])).join();
executors.shutdown();
```

Please help me with how I could stop the pod from restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by editing the Kubernetes **YAML** file. Changed:

1. version `apps` => `batch`
2. kind `Deployment` => `Job`

Also added `restartPolicy: Never` under the spec.